# Sed finding itself and throwing off script results

Tags: bash, sed, grep

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="$1"
RESULT=`ps -a | sed -n /${SERVICE}/p`
MEM=$(ps aux | sort -rk +4 | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print      $4}' | awk 'NR == 1')

if [ "${RESULT:-null}" = null ]; then
echo "$1 is NOT running"
else
echo "$MEM"
fi

if [ "$MEM" -ge 1 ]; then
mailx -s "Alert: server needs to be checked"    me@admins.com
fi
```

The problem with the ps output piped to sed is even if no process is running it finds itself:

```
ps aux | sed -n /nfdump/p
root      30724  0.0  0.0 105252   884 pts/1    S+   14:16   0:00 sed -n /process/p
```

and them my script bypasses the expected result of "service is not running" and goes straight to echo'ing $MEM, which in this case will be 0.0. Does sed have a grep -v grep eqivalent to get itself out of the way?

Comment: Why not pipe it through .... grep -v sed : `ps aux |grep -v sed | sed -n '/nfdump/p'`? but you could also try `ps aux | sed -n '/sed/ n; /nfdump/p'
`. The `/sed/ n;` continues with the next line of input if sed is found.

Comment: Both ways work outside the script but with the script and your first example it bypasses "service is not running" and goes directly to excho'ing $MEM. If I use your second example it stops at "service is not running", even if I run the script against a service that I know is running.

Comment: Are you sure that your sed command is working inside the script? Does it work without the quotes for the part after `-n`? Did you try debugging the script with `bash -x` ?

Comment: btw: at least under Linux you can install a command called `pgrep`, I think that could replace your entire *ps sed pipeline*.

Comment: pgrep works, I am not sure why the pipes to sed worked outside of the script but not inside. points to you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Let me add one more example in addition to my comments above. Sed has indeed an equivalent to `grep -v`: You can negate a match with `/RE/!` (append a `!` to the regex) thus you can try:

```
ps aux | sed -n '/sed/!{ /nfdump/ p;}'
```

Here the part inside `{ ... }` is only applied to lines **not** matching `sed`.

For the record: there is a command `pgrep` that can replace your *ps sed pipeline*, see [pgrep in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) or its manpage.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
ps aux | sed -n '/[n]fdump/p'
```

or :

```
ps aux | grep '[n]fdump'
```

The regex won't be find in the processes list

Comment: Please check out [Bash Pitfalls 31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf31) on why you should never do things like `ps ax | grep gedit`

Comment: I wrote `grep '[n]fdump'`, not `grep nfdump`, inspired by http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc3/#code10. Bash Pitfalls just recommends not to fully rely on grep name on a `ps ax`. This also applies to `sed` commands piped to `ps ax`. I won't rely on it to kill processes but it can be helpful if employed knowledgeably. That said, the best choice might be `pgrep`.

Comment: The provided link also gives `ps aux | grep '[g]edit' ` as an example. Thanks for mentioning `pgrep` in your comment.

Comment: `grep [g]edit` is mentioned as a possible workaround to the `grep gedit` pitfall.

Comment: Thank you for improving this answer.